# How to add/append to existing Web storage in javascript?

Tags: javascript, web-storage

I am trying to add/append to new/existing localStorage using this code:

```
 function add(){

    var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
    var ort = document.getElementById("ort").value;

    var user = {"name":name, "ort":ort};

    var exist = [];

    var tmp = (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")));

    if(tmp)
        exist.push(tmp);
    exist.push(user);
    localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(exist));

    console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users")));
    var obj = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
        console.log('key: ' + i + '\n' + 'value: ' + obj[i]);
    }


}
```

Looking into Chrome developer tools localStorage looks like this:

```
   [[{"name":"a","city":"a"}],{"name":"b","city":"b"}]
```

But what I want is:

```
   [{"name":"a","city":"a"},{"name":"b","city":"b"}]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help appreciated,

Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`localStorage` only store `strings`. You need to `stringify` your `exist` and then save it to `storage`

```
localStorage.setItem("users",JSON.stringify(exist));
```

To retrieve it use `JSON.parse`

```
var exist = JSON.parse(localStorage.exist); //Even for users object do the same
```

**Update**

To only push the objects inside the array `tmp` to `exist` use `map()`:

```
tmp.map(function(item){
 exist.push(item);
})
```

Comment: I updated my code. Now it is close to what I want, but it is getting like this now: [Array[object], Object]. See my updated question.

Comment: Change `localStorage.setItem(JSON.stringify("users",exist));` to `localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify(exist);`

Comment: @user3185491. Its bcoz your `tmp` is an `array` which you push to `exist`. Hence you are pushing an array into another array and it looks like that.

Comment: @Zee how can I then change it to reflect my needs: Array of objects?

Comment: @Zee. Nice. May I ask if tmp.map has some cross browser issues I have to take care of?

Comment: IE<9 may not support it(although I am not sure). There is a polyfill for that in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).